# Compute device list not showing card name when using OpenCL

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I have an AMD Radeon R7 M265, and when I force OPENCL with the batch file it only shows Iceland, Intel HD and the CPU.

I followed this instructions:

1. <kbd>[image: Windows key]</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type `CMD`, press <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>, go to your blender folder. ex:

   ```
   cd C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender
   ```
2. Press <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> and then type: set `CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST=all`
3. Start Blender with `blender.exe`
4. Inside blender go to *File -> User preferences -> System*
5. Under compute device select *OpenCL* and then your card
6. Close the preferences and go to the render panel and select
   device: *GPU Compute*.

   I have the latest beta driver from AMD, but when I try to change the compute device it only shows this list:

   [image: list]

Am I doing something wrong? Is my GPU is not supported? Or is it because it's in development and not every card is supported yet?

I've tried blender v2.74.5, v2.62, and v2.63. Every one gives the same list.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6978/is-opencl-possible-within-blender-either-via-cycles-or-internal and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/turn-on-cycles-gpu-render-on-non-cuda-computers/26195#26195

Comment: For render on graphics cards AMD, in Blender, I recommend using LuxRender. Because support for AMD in Cycles, still under development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMD GPUs appear in blender by the codename of the GPU

Iceland is the name of the processor inside your AMD card. Apparently they name 
their cards with the names of volcanic islands for that series of cards...

Choose that one and good luck.

AMD cards have a long list of problems with cycles. Some of the limitations for OpenCL rendering are listed on the blender manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/features.html

As an alternative, you might want to try other render engines, as detailed on this link: [Alternative Render engines can I use instead of Cycles for AMD Radeon GPUs?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75377/alternative-render-engines-can-i-use-instead-of-cycles-for-amd-radeon-gpus/75403#75403)

Comment: So I tried this but blender crashed. I then tried with experimental and the same thing happend.. Any though?