# Can't get Graphics Chipset AMD Radeon R7 200 Series to work with GPU rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I can not for the life of me setup GPU computing with my R7 200. It is listed as supported, but I can not even see it as an option in the system tab.

All I get is "Oland" as the computing device unde Open CL

Please help!

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31795/compute-device-list-not-showing-card-name-when-using-opencl/31796#31796

Answer (score 1):

Oland is the name of the GPU. AMD cards show as the codename for the chipset.

Select it as your OpenCL device and then enable GPU compute for the scene.

[image]

Keep in mind that not all render features are available when using AMD cards.