# Blender Cycles - Smoke not rendering with AMD GPU (2.78)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, smoke-simulation, gpu

So, I wanted to create a scene with smoke, but this time to render with my AMD GPU. As I saw in the "feature comparison" chart, it SHOULD be supported for AMD by now (2.78).
What is happenning to me, the smoke is not rendered AT ALL. Not a single bit of it. With CPU, it would take about 6 minutes/frame for a 30 frames/second, 11 minutes long movie. It would take for ages to render it all in CPU, so that's why I want it so badly with GPU rendering. I could spare 60-70% of time with GPU, according to simple image renderings, with no smoke, so it should be the same case with smoke too.
So to be clear: CPU render works 100%, so material setup must be good. In the same time, GPU render simply hides the smoke completely, which is quite annoying. I am using Cycles.

If it is a problem with my composition, could you tell me what I did wrong?
[image: Working setup]

Comment: Which AMD GPU do you render on? They are still beta-testing support so probably on some cards something won't work even if it should.

Comment: I render on an R9 280X

Comment: Is rendering speed up at all with the card? [It was already mentioned](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6978/is-opencl-possible-within-blender-either-via-cycles-or-internal) but [things likely changed](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL) although [officially](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#opencl) that card is kind of not supported according to [its architexture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units). Also btw are experimental features enabled?

Comment: It renders waaaay faster in normal cases, as it was mentioned as well. I tried it with Experimental as well, but did not do anything differently.