# Cycles does not render with GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine

My blender system tab shows CAICOS in compute drop down...when i render with graphics processing unit compute.my render screen. is blank.but with CPU its rendering.I do not n have any error messages in console window.I have ATI 6490m graphics card with memory 1gb

Comment: AMD/ATI graphics cards are not supported currently due to driver limitations. You need a CUDA capable card. (Nvidia)

Comment: Is there any other option to use gpu rendering with ati card

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6978/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/452/599

Comment: May I know how to use builds from graphicsall.org

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you are running on newest drivers.

On linux run:
CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST=all ./blender

On windows:
set CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST=all
then run blender

Switch to cycles, go to system settings and select your graphic card.

The performance is limited and initial compiling of the kernel can take few minutes. [But according to this AMD statement](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/160162?start=225&tstart=0), there is a fix slowly coming in. No words on performance improvements though.

Comment: I have the option for gpu compute but render window does not show anything on gpu..But with cpu my scene i rendered completely

Comment: What is your catalyst version and what OS do you have?

Comment: catalyst version 14.4 and OS windows 7.graphics card ATI 6490m

Comment: You may have to install latest beta (14.7) or wait for a  new stable version. But be warned, beta can be unstable.

I got it working on 7970 catalyst 14.6 beta + blender nightly version.